# Run all TCL scripts in a folder

Tags: tcl, vivado

I have a folder with many TCL files, and I need to run them all (in Vivado). How can I save time in running all of them at once? Is there something as easy as: source [path/]*.tcl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first just find all tcl files with the glob command and then go though the list of tcl files and source them.

```
set $dir your/path
foreach file [glob -dir $dir */*.tcl] {
    source $file
}
```

Edit: In difference to Peters example this solution also sources .tcl files in subdirectories (Be sure you want this).

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
foreach script [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *.tcl] {source $script}
```

?

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm)

Answer (score 0):

#### To run all the scripts in a given **directory and its sub-directories** you may use the **tcllib** as follows:

```
package require fileutil
foreach script [fileutil::findByPattern $baseDir *.tcl] {
    source $script
}
```